# Javascript: Copy to Clipboard onkeydown

Tags: javascript

I know this is a kinda difficult task,

**I already found that neat solution:**

http://beckelman.net/post/2009/01/22/Copy-to-Clipboard-with-ZeroClipboard-Flash-10-and-jQuery.aspx

But it seems to require the user to click with the mouse.

**Thats not good for what I've in mind:**

There is a Site containing some dynamic content.
My Javascript split()'s it's content by ; and returns an array.
I want the script to copy the first entry onload and everytime the user press Control V (Paste) it shall copy the next entry (of course, it shall still paste!)

Some really simple stuff,
but it seems hard to code.

Further: what I dont like with this (beckelman.net) script, too, is the fact it needs a framwork.
But I would survive if there is no other solution.

The script should work in IE,
but it would be nice if it works with FF, too.

**Help please!**

**Thx in advance!!**

Answer (score 0):

I have copied to the clipboard using the following within IE, doesn't work in any other browser as far as I know. It will prompt IE to ask the user if they wish to allow the site to work with the clipboard.

```
window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'Your Text');
```